# Java splitting a string on char

Tags: java, split

I have the following string:

```
<stx>1<rs>aaaa<rs>bbbb<rs>cccc<etx>
```

How can i split it in a way that I get 1,aaaa,bbbb,cccc in an array?

I tried splitting on `<rs>` but then I get `<stx>1,aaaa,bbbb,cccc` in my array.

So how do I get rid of that `<stx>`?

`stx`,`rs` and `etx` are chars btw.

thx

Comment: Are *stx* and *etx* always in the string? If so, you can just cut them and then split using *rs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with  the following regex:

```
<\w+>
```

When using it in Java, don't forget to escape the `\`:

```
String[] splitted = myString.split("<\\w+>");
```

Comment: Yes, and if there might be other characters inside the `<>` then it might be better.